# automatically rename multiple columns with piping an elegant way

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for a short and elegant way to select and rename columns in R using dplyr and piping.

I've succeeded to do what I want, but it's clumbsy and hard to script so I'm looking for a better way.

Here is the thing that work:

```
tab <- as.data.frame(matrix(round(runif(15,0,50)),3,5))
colnames(tab) <- c("badvar1", "badvar2","badname1","badname2","badname3")
tab %>% 
   select(c("badname1","badname2","badname3")) %>%
   rename(goodname1 = badname1, goodname2 = badname2 ,goodname3 = badname3)

   goodname1 goodname2 goodname3
1        48        32        28
2        38        31         5
3        19        43        41
```

The problem here is that I have more than 3 variables to rename (imagine 50) so I do not want to have to manually write 50 times `newvar1=var1, newvar2=var2, ...`.  So I was looking for something in the spirit of this next script but it doesn't work:

```
vector_of_good_var_name <- c("goodname1","goodname2","goodname3")

tab %>% 
   select(c("badname1","badname2","badname3")) %>%
     rename(vector_of_good_var_name)
Error: All arguments must be named
```

I've also try this (very not elegant, and didn't work anyway...):

```
test <- list("badname1","badname2","badname3")
names(test) <- c("goodname1","goodname2","goodname3")
tab %>% 
   select(c("badname1","badname2","badname3")) %>%
     rename(test)
Error: All arguments must be named
```

Any idea how to better script renaming variable with piping?

Comment: `tab %>% select(...) %>% setNames(vector_of_good_var_name)`?

Comment: Yes @r2evans!  That simple!  post it as an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. `dplyr`: `tab %>% rename_(.dots = test)`

   This has the bonus of using named renames, so the order of your `test` variable contents and names does not matter.

   This has the disadvantage that `rename_` is [soft-deprecated](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/manip.r#L462-L466); not certain on the timeline. This suggests that the recommendation will shift to `rename_at`, `rename_all`, and/or `rename_if`, requiring an ancillary function to translate between old names and new names.
2. Base R (renaming, still using the `dplyr` pipeline): `tab %>% select(...) %>% setNames(vector_of_good_var_name)`

   I don't think `setNames` will be deprecated any time soon ...

Comment: `%>%` is not base R  :-)

Comment: G5W: ok, you got me, but ... it's already loaded in the OP environment, so I cheated ... but you are correct.